Como poner el formato de fecha?
En Android Studio agregue un text de tipo date pero no puedo darle formato ya que a la hora de agregarlo solo me aparece el pad numérico y en mi servidor solo se muestra esto:
fechaVencimiento: "150527"
Quiero darle el formato 13/05/2024

Para formatear una fecha para la configuración regional actual, utilice uno de los métodos de fábrica estáticos:
 myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate);
 myString = DateFormat.getPatternInstance(DateFormat.YEAR_ABBR_MONTH).format(myDate);

También puede utilizar un DateFormat para convertir el string de nuevo a date.
myDate = df.parse(myString);

Respuesta sacada de developer.android.com/DateFormat
Espero te sirva.
